# How to send data in jsoup connection?

Tags: connection, jsoup

I need to send data in jsoup connection request. This is the Form Data that I can see in chrome developer console.

`{"method":"Catalog.search","params":{"pag":1,"business_url":"electrodomesticos","category_url":"climatizacion","subcategory_url":"","valmin":-1,"valmax":-1}}`

This is my code for doing this

```
    String phpUrl = "url of .php";
    Connection conn = Jsoup.connect(phpUrl).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36").referrer(referer).maxBodySize(0).timeout(Main.TIMEOUT);

    Map  <String,String>  myMap= new HashMap <String, String>();
    myMap.put("method", "Catalog.search");
    //myMap.put("params", "{}");
    myMap.put("pag", "1");
    myMap.put("business_url", "electrodomesticos");
    myMap.put("category_url", "climatizacion" );
    myMap.put("subcategory_url", "" );
    myMap.put("valmin", "-1" );
    myMap.put("valmax", "-1");
    conn.data(myMap);
    conn.post();
    Connection.Response respon = conn.execute();
```

I tried few more combinations but I aways get http 500 error. I know that my syntax is wrong. So please can somebody tell me the right syntax to send that data.

Comment: Could you provide the url?

Comment: url of that php script is ->(http://www.coordiutil.com/rpc/server.php ) Actually, as far as I can understand ,some javascript is calling the function/method "Catalog.search" of server.php and others are parameters for that function/method.After that the php script is sending me some json response. I need to capture that response. Let me know if there is some other way of doing this.

Comment: Visiting the above url, I receive and empty page. No javascript in the response. Can you give me the url of the page that calls http://www.coordiutil.com/rpc/server.php  ?

Comment: http://www.coordiutil.com/electrodomesticos-climatizacion . I need to fetch the url of all the items in that page.

Comment: curl http://www.coordiutil.com/rpc/server.php -v -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch" -H "Accept-Language:es-ES,es;q=0.8" -H "Connection:keep-alive" -H "X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest" -d '{"method":"Catalog.search","params":{"pag":1,"business_url":"tecnologia","category_url":"conectividad","subcategory_url":"","valmin":-1,"valmax":-1}}:' -H "Content-Length:149"  This curl command gives me exact result( that is a json file) but I need to do this using jsoup.

Comment: business_url and category_url are variable according to the page.

Comment: +1. The problem with jsoup is that it uses urlencoder and that messes up your data. I only realized when I saw your raw data commit. I deleted my answer since it didn't help at all. I've learnt something though which is great. Thank you. Have fun.

Comment: @alkis Can you please mail me the answer you posted and then deleted. I might need it.My Email id is shiv.kumar.mahadev@gmail.com

Comment: I've undeleted it. Better here since It might be useful to someone else too. Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

This command

```
curl coordiutil.com/rpc/server.php -v -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch" -H "Accept-Language:es-ES,es;q=0.8" -H "Connection:keep-alive" -H "X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest" -d '{"method":"Catalog.search","params":{"pag":1,"business_url":"tecnologia","categ‌​ory_url":"conectividad","subcategory_url":"","valmin":-1,"valmax":-1}}:' -H "Content-Length:149"
```

could be something like this, but jsoup will use URLEncoder.encode() on the data.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.coordiutil.com/rpc/server.php")
                            //.userAgent("curl/7.34.0")
                            .header("Accept", "application/json")
                            .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch")
                            .header("Accept-Language", "es-ES,es;q=0.8")
                            .header("Connection", "keep-alive")
                            .header("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
                            //.header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                            .data("{\"method\":\"Catalog.search\",\"params\":{\"pag\":1,\"business_url\":\"tecnologia\",\"categ‌​ory_url\":\"conectividad\",\"subcategory_url\":\"\",\"valmin\":-1,\"valmax\":-1}}", "")
                            .post(); 

            System.out.println(doc.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Since you are sending a rather odd POST request, just use HttpURLConnection, without Jsoup on top of it.

```
        String rawData = "{\"method\":\"Catalog.search\",\"params\":{\"pag\":\"1\",\"business_url\":\"tecnologia\",\"categ‌​ory_url\":\"conectividad\",\"subcategory_url\":\"fkdj\",\"valmin\":\"-1\",\"valmax\":\"-1\"}}";
        String url = "http://www.coordiutil.com/rpc/server.php";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        //add reuqest header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "es-ES,es;q=0.8");
        con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
        con.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");

        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStreamWriter w = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");

        w.write(rawData);
        w.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        System.out.println("Response code : " + responseCode);
        System.out.println(response.toString());
```

Comment: I already tried this. But no success. I am still getting http 500 error :( . https://github.com/purblind/jsoup/commit/e6bb8a2abc7ef38ba5931214ff58f5ee64760659 . Right now I am working on this commit. I am tring to extends few classes and want to implement rawData() into it.

Comment: https://github.com/purblind/jsoup/commit/e6bb8a2abc7ef38ba5931214ff58f5ee64760659  .. <- This works, I will post the code soon. :)

Comment: Exactly, my data are the key with no value.

Comment: Could you give me exactly the string as you pass it to jsoup?

Comment: I dont know if I understand your question very well or not. I have no control over server script ( server.php) . All I know is when some .js  function call that server.php and pass some parameters, the server.php gives me some json response. I know all this by inspecting elements in chrome developer tool. Now I have to do this using jsoup library in JAVA project. In short I have no knowledge or control over server.php. I have to adjust my JAVA project according to server.php.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry then. My bad. I updated my answer by providing a solution without jsoup.

Answer (score 0):

The [latest jsoup's release (1.10.2)](https://jsoup.org/news/release-1.10.2) has the [`Connection#requestBody`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#requestBody-java.lang.String-) method, that allow the POST's execution using a JSON as body. The code should look something like that:

```
  Connection connection;
  Response response;
  String url = "url of .php";
  String body = "{\n"
          + "   \"method\": \"Catalog.search\",\n"
          + "   \"params\": {\n"
          + "       \"pag\": 1,\n"
          + "       \"business_url\": \"electrodomesticos\",\n"
          + "       \"category_url\": \"climatizacion\",\n"
          + "       \"subcategory_url\": \"\",\n"
          + "       \"valmin\": -1,\n"
          + "       \"valmax\": -1\n"
          + "   }\n"
          + "}";

  connection = Jsoup.connect(url)
          .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36") // User-Agent of Chrome 55
          .referrer("my referer") // Custom Referer
          .header("Accept", "application/json")
          .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch")
          .header("Accept-Language", "es-ES,es;q=0.8")
          .header("Connection", "keep-alive")
          .header("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
          .requestBody(body)
          .maxBodySize(0)
          .timeout(0)
          .method(Method.POST); // Infinite / Milis time

  response = connection.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 String[] POST_DATA = new String[]{KEY, VALUE, KEY2, VALUE2}; 
    Response response = Jsoup.connect(URL)
    .data(POST_DATA )
    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
    .execute;
```

reference:
https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#requestBody-java.lang.String-